# Is it permissible to use the "Tahor" bedikah app?

Tags: technology, niddah

[Tahor App](http://tahorapp.com/) is a Miami-based organization which created an app to allow women to "anonymously send pictures of their Bedikah cloths to a Rabbi with Tahor app’s Rabbinically approved technology."

May this app be used? Have any rabbis explicitly approved or disapproved of it?

Comment: This was recently mentioned in one of the Halacha Shiurim given by Rabbi Kier. The Shiur can be heard here: http://www.torasemes.com/~audio/Rabbi_Sharfman/Picture_Imperfect_Utilizing_Photos_In_Hilchos_Mezuzah_and_Niddah_February_3_2019.mp3 (more Shiurim can be found here: https://www.ytcteam.org/shiurim_sharfman.php?school=alumni). In short, he was very strongly opposed to the app.

Answer (score 6):

First, some background information: [Tahor](http://tahorapp.com/) is an application connecting women with *rabbanim* to answer questions on *bedika* cloths. The application uses [various techniques](http://tahorapp.com/frequently-asked-questions/) to ensure proper color and size calibration.

The app developers state clearly that the app is only meant to be used for "women who either cannot, or do not, ask their Taharat Hamishpacha questions to a Rav."

> We at Tahor completely encourage all women to bring their bedikas to
>   their Rav. However, we recognize the fact that many women do not do
>   this. It is for these women that Tahor app was created. Our goal at
>   Tahor is to make sure all these women can be included in this mitzvah.

Their [rabbinic authorities](http://tahorapp.com/our-rabbis/) are

- R K. Auman, the former president of the Rabbinical Council of America and the Dean of the Yoatzot Halacha Program in the United States
- R E. Davis, a YU graduate and the Morah D’asrah at the Young Israel of Hollywood, FL
- R Ariel Edry, a Talmudic University graduate who serves as a rav
- R D Bixon, a YU graduate and the Rav of Beth Israel in Miami Beach

The app has generated some opposition: for instance, from R Sholom Ber Shuchat, a Chabad Rabbi and Dayan from Agudas Harabonim of the US and Canada, who came out against its use. (See [here](https://www.collive.com/show_news.rtx?id=45533) and [there](https://www.collive.com/show_news.rtx?id=45536) for Tahor's response, and [here](http://crownheights.info/chabad-news/575559/chabad-rabbi-pulls-endorsement-tahor-app/) for additional opposition from Chabad rabbis).

Ultimately every woman should [ask her own rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi) if he supports the use of this app for cases where she cannot direct her questions directly to him.

Comment: Small point: Are you sure it's only meant to be used בדיעבד? "If you are traveling and don’t have access to a Rav, or you don’t normally ask your Rabbi family purity questions..." One of these sounds like שעת הדחק, the other לכתחילה.

Comment: You are right and I edited to also update some of the language and reflect the latest iteration of their site. Thanks!

Comment: Although this site encourages people to ask 'their rabbi', adding that on about a site which is geared to people who don't ask their rabbi seems strange.